# display listview items in excel sheet

Tags: wpf, excel, vba, listview, for-loop

I am displaying my results from an SQL search in excel from a WPF application. It initally displays them in a listview and the user can select the option to export to excel which is working fine.

The error i am having is, if there are say 5 results in the SQL result and displayed in the listview, when i export to excel it is only displaying 4 results plus the SQL table headings...

```
For i As Integer = 1 To dtMainSQLData.Rows.Count

            For j As Integer = 1 To dtMainSQLData.Columns.Count

                If i = 1 Then

                    sheet.Cells(i, j) = dcCollection(j - 1).ToString()

                Else

                    sheet.Cells(i, j) = dtMainSQLData.Rows(i - 1)(j - 1).ToString()

                End If

            Next

        Next
```

Does anyone see a problem with the about loop for printing out the SQL results to excel

Answer (score 0):

this is your problem:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To dtMainSQLData.Rows.Count
```

If you skip the first and you handle decreasing it by 1 when you access your items, you must go up to To `dtMainSQLData.Rows.Count + 1`

Personally I would start from 0 like this:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To dtMainSQLData.Rows.Count
    For j As Integer = 0 To dtMainSQLData.Columns.Count
        If i = 0 Then
            sheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = dcCollection(j).ToString()
        Else
            sheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = dtMainSQLData.Rows(i)(j).ToString()
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Getting error saying cannot find column 19 now, any idea? guessing its because it has reached the last column (18) and adding 1 leads to not finding 19?

Comment: Where does the exception occur?

Comment: if i = 0 then... when it hits the last column the error is thrown

Comment: There are 19 columns sorry

Comment: Put a break point and check the value of dtMainSQLData.Columns.Count you probably have 20 columns but the last one is kind of null or empty I don't know.

Comment: where dcCollection comes from?

Comment: Dim dcCollection As DataColumnCollection = dtMainSQLData.Columns

Comment: Can you do dtMainSQLData.Columns(j) instead of dcCollection ?

Comment: changed it there but still the same error. (cannot find column 19)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101300/discussion-between-csharpwinphonexaml-and-aaron-c).

Comment: It's not a chat it's only called so

Comment: access denied sorry.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging csharpwinphonexaml's answer I got it working. I have to add an additional IF to check if it was at the last position.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To dtMainSQLData.Rows.Count
            For j As Integer = 0 To dtMainSQLData.Columns.Count - 1
                If i = 0 Then
                    sheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = dtMainSQLData.Columns(j).ToString()
                ElseIf i = dtMainSQLData.Rows.Count Then
                    sheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = dtMainSQLData.Rows(0)(j).ToString()
                Else
                    sheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = dtMainSQLData.Rows(i)(j).ToString()
                End If
            Next
        Next
```